# Text recognizer control is not working in Xamarin forms Android - Release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, scanning

We are facing the mentioned issue - Text recognizer control not working in Xamarin forms Android - Release mode.

Xamarin forms version - 4.4, OCR scanning custom controls.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Your post contains no useful details we could use to help you.  You haven't supplied any code, explained what "text recognizer control" you are using, or described the problem beyond "not working"